# Modified Newton's Method multiplicity

Tags: numerical-methods

I have an assignment question that I have no idea how to solve. It goes like this:

The **multiplicity** of the zero $x^*$ is the least integer $m$ such that $f^{(k)}(x^*)=0$ for $0 \le k \lt m$, but $f^{(m)}(x^*) \neq 0$. Show analytically that in the case of a zero of multiplicity $m$, the **modified Newton's Method** $$x_{n+1}=x_n-m \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$$ is quadratically convergent.

I have no clue how to solve this. Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the answer to that one though.

Comment: Possible duplicate as well of  http://math.stackexchange.com/q/312819

Comment: It reduces the problem to one with a simple root. The other variant is to analyze the function $f(x)=(x-a)^mq(x)$ and its derivative to find the next best root approximation from these two data points.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!