# Newton raphson convergence order

Tags: numerical-methods

As you know convergence order of newton raphson method is:

$
E_{t,i+1}=-\frac {f''(x_r)}{2f'(x_r)}E_{t,i}^2
$

What's newton raphson method convergence order if $f'(x_r)=0$.

Comment: Well, check $f(x) = x^4$

Comment: The convergence becomes very very slow. Does one speak of convergence order in that case ? I don't know.

Comment: How can I do that??Is it correct to just check a single function?

Comment: You get linear convergence with convergence factor $1-\frac1m$, where $m$ is the multiplicity of the root. Practically related is that Newton's method for polynomials, when you start far outside the root region, only sees the leading term and thus converges slowly, linearly with rate $1-\frac1{\deg p}$ until it sees the root cluster closely as single roots.

Comment: Could you prove that!

Answer (score 0):

In the hypothesis of the Newton's method there is one about $f'$ calculated on the sequence $\{x_r\}$, i.e. 
$$
f'(x_r) \neq 0 \quad \forall \, x_r \in \{x_r\}
$$

From a geometrical point of view if for an $r$ happen $f'(x_r) = 0$ you find a point such that has got the derivate parallel to $x$ axis, so you can't intersect it.

Instead if your case is 
$$
f(\alpha) = 0 \quad f'(\alpha) = 0
$$
i.e $\alpha$ is the root (I change the notation because $x_r$ is simular to a sequence) and the derivate calculate in $\alpha$ is zero ($\alpha$ is a root with multiciplity $>1$) see this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312819/rate-of-convergence-of-modified-newtons-method-for-multiple-roots). Dominique's answer explains the convergence argument in general for multiple roots.