# Modified Newton's method - denominator 0

Tags: numerical-methods

While I find information on Modified Newton's method, [I have read this post from mathstackexchange.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312819/rate-of-convergence-of-modified-newtons-method-for-multiple-roots)

In short, a modified Newton's method, $x_{n+1} = x_n - k\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)} ,$ such that ,in the case of $k>1$ , and $f$ has a root of multiplicity $k$ at $r$ and $h(r) \neq 0$. it can be written in the form $f(x)=(x−r)^kh(x)$ where $h(r)≠0$.

Also, we have $x_{k+1} = g(x_k)$ and $g(x) := x - k f(x)/f'(x)$

While I show that it is quadratically convergent, we encounter a equation like:

$e_{n+1} = x_{n+1} - r = g(x_n) - r \approx g(r) + g'(r) (x_n - r) - r = g'(r) e_n$

By Taylor's expansions.

Here, I am not able to understand that $g'(r) $ has a denominator 0, i.e,

$g'(r) = 1-t(r)/f'(r)^2$ , for some $t(r)$ but we know that $f'(r)=0. $

So is it not valid answer?

Comment: At a root with higher multiplicity, the curve is tangent to the ordinate axis to a higher order. Which means that the derivatives below that order=multiplicity are zero.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Could be more specific please?

Comment: What is the derivative of $f$ in terms of $h$?

Comment: @LutzLehmann Say, $k=2$ then $f' = (x-r)h(x) + (x-r)^2h'(x)$

Comment: Yes, so the factors $(x-r)$ cancel and the limit is finite.